# Are there plans for ImmutableEnumSet in Java 7?

Tags: java, collections, enums, java-7

I want to have all the efficiencies of EnumSet and pass it around without worrying that somebody would modify it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get an immutable EnumSet with Google collections (Guava).

---

**Resources :**

- [Guava home page](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)
- [Google-collections bug tracker - immutable enum set convenience constructor](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/issues/detail?id=153)
- [Google documentation - Sets.immutableEnumSet()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#immutableEnumSet(java.lang.Iterable))

Comment: Guava is getting to be an awesome library. This rocks! +1

Comment: Would have accepted it if `Sets.immutableEnumSet` would have returned a public `ImmutableEnumSet` class, not just `ImmutableSet`.  Though I will try to make a request to do so.

Comment: What benefit do you see this public ImmutableEnumSet type having, I wonder?

Comment: @KevinBourrillion: having explicit different iteration order (compared to ImmutableSet)?

Comment: @Alexander From [ImmutableCollectionsExplained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained): "Except for sorted collections, order (of Immutable collections) is preserved from construction time.", so I think this deserves to be the answer.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion: Some public methods like complement or getUniverse?

Answer (score 12):

What's wrong with `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` wrapping an `EnumSet`?

True, the original `EnumSet` is still mutable, but as long as you discard the original reference, it's as good as immutable inside the wrapper.

**edit:** OK, since `EnumSet` doesn't offer any instance methods over and above the `Set` interface, the only reason for not using this solution is that the `EnumSet` type is useful for documentation purposes, and you lose that when wrapping it in a `Set`.  Other than that, `EnumSet` behaviour will be preserved.

Comment: It doesn't have all methods of an `EnumSet`

Comment: @Colin what methods would that be? You could still use the static methods to create the enumset before wrapping it, and I don't see any new instance methods in enumset that other sets don't have either.

Comment: @skaffman.  I think I want it mostly for documentation purposes.  The thing about EnumSet is that it specifies a certain iteration order, and if you use `Set` in place of `EnumSet` it may produce different results than you expect: somebody sees the `Set` in method signature and passes in `HashSet` for example.  Without this requirement your suggestion would be fine.  BTW, the `EnumSet` does not have additional methods ( only constructors ), though it would be really nice to have `first`, `last` and `reverseIterator` in some cases.

Comment: @seanizer, Hum, I didn't noticed that the new methods where static.

Comment: @alexander, @colin there wouldn't be much point in letting a set have additional methods that are not backed by the set interface, it would break the conventions of the collections framework. So additional methods would require an additional (sub) interface and that just wouldn't be justified by the needs of one single set implementation class.

Comment: @seanizer: That's not really true, there are precedents in the collections framework for class-specific methods that don't break the interface, e.g. `ArrayList.ensureCapacity()`

Comment: @seanizer. `TreeSet` is still a set, but does have additional methods.  If there is a need, there must be a way.  The problem with `EnumSet` is really a problem with `Enum`.  I would not have minded to coin MyEnumSet for my framework, but because `Enum` is so special I do not have access to its secret sauce ( they even called it SharedSecrets ) the way Java framework developers do.

Comment: @alexander but treeset is backed by the navigablemap interface, which is implemented by more than one class. There are no non-interface public methods in treeset.

Comment: If you want to create a complement then `EnumSet.complementOf()` requires an `EnumSet` as argument.