# Java unmodifiable set casted to an enumset

Tags: java, collections, set

I would like to make test unmodifiable, so I'm using `Collections.unmodifiableSet` and casting, as per [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603830/2719355)

```
EnumSet<T> test = (EnumSet) Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(T.Enum.A));
```

But I keep getting the following. What's wrong with the above?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet cannot be cast to java.util.EnumSet
```

Comment: I guess the error is pretty descriptive: `EnumSet` class is not an `UnmodifiableSet` class. By the way, that answer you post refers to wrapping an `UnmodifiableSet` in an `EnumSet`. It is not about typecasting one with the another.

Comment: I see. So what's the correct way to get an `unmodifiableEnumSet`, should I just use Guava?

Comment: Wrapping an `UnmodifiableSet` in an `EnumSet`...

Answer (score 6):

The method `Collections.unmodifiableSet` takes a `Set` and returns another `Set` implementation that delegates all read access method calls to the underlying set and blocks all write access method calls by throwing an exception.

In other words: The `Set` that is returned is not an `EnumSet`. Use it as follows:

```
Set<T.Enum> test = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(T.Enum.A));
```

Edit: As all methods of class `EnumSet` are static, there is no advantage of working with `EnumSet` instead of `Set`; so the code above should work fine in all cases.

Comment: The method I'm calling using `test`, requires for it to be a `EnumSet`, not a `Set`.

Comment: There are no special methods in `EnumSet` beyond those defined in the `Set` interface, so that's fine. You should never have `EnumSet` as the declared type of a variable or field, just like you should never have `HashSet` or `ArrayList` as a declared type. You only need to know about these implementation types when you're constructing instances, not after that anymore.

Comment: @StenKin There's your problem then, you should change the signature of the code your calling using `test`, because it's incorrect to use `EnumSet` as the declared type of a variable (a method parameter in this case). Just use `Set<T>` instead.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Ah, yes! Only static methods! You're right.